# ODBC: user data source

Tags: odbc

Within the ODBC admin tool, there are the following Platform column values.  How do you get ODBC to display 32/64 bit?  We're only seeing 32-bit and need for it to show 32/64 bit in the Platform column.

Possible values for the Platform column:

- "32-bit" means that the DSN can only be used in a 32-bit application and can only be configured in the 32-bit ODBC Administrator tool (WoW64 mode).
- "64-bit" means that the DSN can only be used in a 64-bit application and can only be configured in the 64-bit ODBC Administrator tool (Native mode).
- "32/64-bit" means that the DSN can be used in both a 32-bit application and 64-bit application and can be configured in both the 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC Administrator tool (WoW64 mode and Native mode).
- "N/A" means that the DSN cannot be used in either a 32-bit application or 64-bit application, and cannot be configured in either the 32-bit or 64-bit ODBC Administrator tool (WoW64 mode and Native mode). You need to reinstall the corresponding driver or remove the DSN.

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC driver installed?

Comment: when you say driver, do you mean the different odbc.exe in syswow vs 32 folder?A 64-bit version of the Microsoft Windows operating system includes the following versions of the Microsoft Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) Data Source Administrator tool (Odbcad32.exe):
The 32-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64 folder.
The 64-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\System32 folder.

Comment: I am not talking about the tool.  I am talking about the drivers that allow you to communicate with the database.  What type of database are you trying to communicate with?  You should be as specific as possible.  We cannot answer your question without knowing this information.